# Java - compilation error - cannot find symbol - variable Terminal

Tags: java, terminal, compiler-errors, compilation

I have just started learning Java for first time.
I have an issue when compiling the following code.

```
public class Conversion {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    double euros;
    double dollars;
    System.out.println("Sum in euros? ");
    euros = Terminal.lireDouble();
    dollars = euros * 1.118;
    System.out.println("Sum in dollars: ");
    System.out.println(dollars);
}
```

}

I get the following error message:

> /Users/Mathieu/IdeaProjects/Conversion/src/com/company/Conversion.java:9:17
> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable Terminal   location:
> class com.company.Conversion

Please, could you help me ?
What is wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `Terminal.lireDouble()`?

Comment: I do not know, that is from our professor notebook.

Comment: What is supposed to be read in Java like cin (c++) or scanf (in C) or Console.ReadLine() (in c#) ?

Comment: Well the compiler doesn't know what it means either. Maybe your professor notebook contains some more information somewhere about importing `Terminal` before you use it.

Comment: *What is supposed to be read in Java like cin (c++) or scanf (in C) or Console.ReadLine() (in c#) ?* ... read about `System.in` and the `Scanner` class.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get input from the user use this

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Conversion {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double euros;
        double dollars;
        System.out.println("Sum in euros? ");
        euros = in.nextDouble();
        dollars = euros * 1.118;
        System.out.println("Sum in dollars: ");
        System.out.println(dollars);
    }
   }
```

Scanner is used to get input from the user